# ng-repeat после обновления не обновляет DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

```
<header id="tabHeader">
    <div class="h-head" ng-click="switchTab($index)" ng-repeat="key in data">{{key.grad}}</div>
    <div class="addHead" ng-click="addTab()">+</div>
</header>
```

Есть вкладки, по нажатию на addHead, добавляется новая

```
$scope.addTab = function () {
    $scope.data.push({grad : 'new grad'});
    removeActive();
    console.log(headers.length);
    makeActive(headers.length-1);
};
```

Добавляю к массиву данных еще один объект и ng-repeat вырисовывает новую вкладку, но функция makeActive не видит нового элемента.
Вот как берется коллекция вкладок:

```
var headers = document.getElementById('tabHeader').children;
```

Функция:

```
function makeActive(i) {
    console.log(headers);
    headers[i].classList.add('active');
    $scope.activeData = $scope.data[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда используете angular забудьте про манипулирование DOM напрямую, это необходимо лишь в крайних случаях

Вместо `headers[i].classList.add('active');` есть `ng-class`

Будет достаточно запоминать индекс активной вкладки (`$scope.activeTab = index`). 
В итоге классы можно будет присваивать очень легко:

```
<header id="tabHeader">
    <div class="h-head" ng-class="{active: $index == activeTab}" ng-click="switchTab($index)" ng-repeat="key in data">{{key.grad}}</div>
    <div class="addHead" ng-click="addTab()">+</div>
</header>`
```

В данном случае к выбранному табу будет применятся класс `active`

PS: не забываем установить по-умолчанию первую вкладку активной